# ggplot2: can't remove space from density plot and axis in discrete scale (expand not working)

Tags: r, ggplot2

given a dataset containing values of two different variables:

```
> head(datplot)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  liking value
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 var1   -1.85
2 var2    2.27
3 var1   -1.98
4 var2    1.96
5 var1   -1.95
6 var2    1.80
```

I am trying to plot the following plot.

```
p1 <- ggplot(datplot, aes(x=value, y=factor(liking, level = c("var1", "var2")), group = liking, color = liking)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.1, 1))) +
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(), inherit.aes = FALSE, mapping = aes(
    ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, xmin = -0.1 * min(stdev), xmax = 0.1 * max(stdev)
  ), fill = "black", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 0.75, size = 0.5, alpha=0.5, show.legend = FALSE,
                      quantile_lines = TRUE, quantiles = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), 
                      vline_color = alpha("white", 0.5), aes(fill = liking)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#cc2701", "#004d8d"), breaks = c("var1", "var2")) +   
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#cc2701", "#004d8d"), breaks = c("var1", "var2")) +
  labs(title="ggplot title") +
  ylab("liking") +
  xlab("values") +
  theme()
```

Which delivers this:

[image: plot]

As you can see, I have tried to get rid of the space from `var1` to the x axis with `scale_y_discrete(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.1, 1)))`, also tried with `scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))` and `scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(0,0))` but it does not reduce the space and I cannot find the answer why.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not related to the expansion of the scale but to setting `ymin=0` in `geom_rect`. As a consequence, your y axis will start at zero (just to clarify: `var1` will correspond to 1, `var2` to 2) and you get a "gap" of length 1 below the first category which can't be removed by setting the expansion. To fix that, you could use `ymin=-Inf`.

Using some fake example data based on `iris`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

datplot <- iris[iris$Species != "setosa", c("Sepal.Length", "Species")]
names(datplot) <- c("value", "liking")
datplot$liking <- ifelse(datplot$liking == "versicolor", "var1", "var2")
datplot$value <- datplot$value - mean(datplot$value)

stdev <- sd(datplot$value)

ggplot(datplot, aes(
  x = value, y = factor(liking, level = c("var1", "var2")),
  group = liking, color = liking
)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 0))) +
  geom_rect(
    data = data.frame(), aes(
      ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
      xmin = -0.1 * min(stdev), xmax = 0.1 * max(stdev)
    ), fill = "black", alpha = 0.1,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_density_ridges(
    scale = 0.75, size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE,
    quantile_lines = TRUE, quantiles = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975),
    vline_color = alpha("white", 0.5), aes(fill = liking)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("#cc2701", "#004d8d"),
    breaks = c("var1", "var2"),
    aesthetics = c("color", "fill")
  ) +
  labs(title = "ggplot title", y = "liking", x = "values") +
  theme()
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.21
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic with geom_segment was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` aesthetic instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
```

[image]